# How to holepunch a block inside a $productCollection loop?

Tags: magento-enterprise, holepunching

I'm trying to create a block inside the category/list page, that is not cached by FPC. Specifically, I have an addtocart block that requires some logic depending on user configuration, this configuration can be changed from the topnav and it will cause a page refresh when changed. So it a customer is looking at the category/list page, and they have option A selected, something should render. If they have option B, another thing should render.

Here is what I have so far:

cache.xml

    `<config>
        <placeholders>
            <custommodule_catalog_product_list_addtocart>
                <block>custommodule/catalog_product_list_addtocart</block>
                <name>custommodule.addtocart</name>
                <template>custommodule/catalog/product/list/addtocart.phtml</template>
                <placeholder>CUSTOMMODULE_CATALOG_PRODUCT_LIST_ADDTOCART</placeholder>
                <container>CustomModule_Model_Caching_Container_List_Addtocart</container>
                <cache_lifetime>1</cache_lifetime>
            </custommodule_catalog_product_list_addtocart>
        </placeholders>
    </config>`

container

```
class CustomModule_Model_Caching_Container_List_Addtocart extends Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract
{

    protected function _getCacheId()
    {
        return 'CUSTOMMODULE_CATALOG_PRODUCT_List_ADDTOCART' . $this->_getIdentifier();
    }

    protected function _getIdentifier()
    {
        return microtime();
    }

    protected function _renderBlock()
    {
        $blockClass = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('block');
        $template = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('template');
        $block = new $blockClass;
        $block->setTemplate($template);
        $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
        $block->setLayout($layout);

        return $block->toHtml();

    }

    protected function _saveCache($data, $id, $tags = array(), $lifetime = null)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

block

```
class CustomModule_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Addtocart extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
}
```

layout.xml

    `<catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <block type="custommodule/catalog_product_list_addtocart"
                   name="custommodule.addtocart"
                   template="custommodule/catalog/product/list/addtocart.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>`

catalog/product/list.phtml

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
...
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custommodule.addtocart'); ?>
...
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This "formula" works for me just fine in other places, like the PDP. However, I can't figure out a way to give my block the $_product we are iterating.
It works fine on first load (after clearing cache).

Any help on how to pass data to that block inside the loop?

Thanks!